# Getting a string out of a Key?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm creating an encoded key like this:

```
public static String generateKey(String username) {
    return KeyFactory.keyToString(
        KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), username));
}
```

is it possible to decompose the key to get the original username out of it?

```
String encoded = generateKey("bob");
String decoded = KeyFactory.decodeKey(encoded);
// decoded = "bob".
```

Thanks

--------- Edit: How I'm storing the key -------------------------

```
@PrimaryKey 
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value="true") 
private String mKey;
```

Comment: It all depends on the encoding. Some are reversible some are not. What kind of encoding are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer - I'm just using the "gae.encoded-pk" label - is that the encoding type? Otherwise I'm using the encoding method above from KeyFactory, not sure there's a chance to choose an encoding type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not a great idea to try and extract one, even if the key returned currently looks reversible. From the [KeyFactory documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.html):

> Clients should not make any
>   assumptions about this return value,
>   except that it is a websafe string
>   that does not need to be quoted when
>   used in HTML or in URLs.

Comment: That is a bummer! Was hoping that I could decode it, would save me from having to store the username as another string in the class.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(